# How to convert ActiveRecord results into an array of hashes

Tags: arrays, activerecord, hash

I have an ActiveRecord result of a find operation:

```
tasks_records = TaskStoreStatus.find(
  :all,
  :select => "task_id, store_name, store_region",
  :conditions => ["task_status = ? and store_id = ?", "f", store_id]
)
```

Now I want to convert this results into an array of hashes like this:

```
[0] ->  { :task_d => 10, :store_name=> "Koramanagala", :store_region=> "India" }

[1] -> { :task_d => 10, :store_name=> "Koramanagala", :store_region=> "India" }

[2] ->  { :task_d => 10, :store_name=> "Koramanagala", :store_region=> "India" }
```

so that I will be able to iterate through the array and to add more elements to hashes and later to convert the result into `JSON` for my API response. How can I do this?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/20794398/165673

Answer (score 262):

### as_json

You should use `as_json` method which converts ActiveRecord objects to Ruby Hashes despite its name

```
tasks_records = TaskStoreStatus.all
tasks_records = tasks_records.as_json

# You can now add new records and return the result as json by calling `to_json`

tasks_records << TaskStoreStatus.last.as_json
tasks_records << { :task_id => 10, :store_name => "Koramanagala", :store_region => "India" }
tasks_records.to_json
```

### serializable_hash

You can also convert any ActiveRecord objects to a Hash with `serializable_hash` and you can convert any ActiveRecord results to an Array with `to_a`, so for your example :

```
tasks_records = TaskStoreStatus.all
tasks_records.to_a.map(&:serializable_hash)
```

And if you want an ugly solution for Rails prior to v2.3

```
JSON.parse(tasks_records.to_json) # please don't do it
```

Comment: +1 For suggesting serializable_hash - this is the first time I've ever come across an answer that mentions this. Sadly I am currently using the last JSON solution, but will now look at using serializable_hash. I just need to find out how to include the class name with each record, same as you might get if you include root in JSON.

Comment: @Dom웃 If I understand correctly see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17090891/how-to-convert-activerecord-results-into-an-array-of-hashes-including-root

Comment: @Dom see my answer below.

Comment: Another possible way is `tasks_records = TaskStoreStatus.all.map(&:attributes)`.

Comment: Really great solutions over here, but my question could be **What are the benefits of using either `.as_json`, `&:serializable_hash` and `&:attributes` ? Does it has to do with ActiveRecord helpers or directly with performance?** thanks in advance guys! @Dom @Rigo @Fredrik E

Answer (score 53):

May be?

```
result.map(&:attributes)
```

If you need symbols keys:

```
result.map { |r| r.attributes.symbolize_keys }
```

Answer (score 15):

For current ActiveRecord (4.2.4+) there is a method `to_hash` on the `Result` object that returns an array of hashes. You can then map over it and convert to symbolized hashes:

```
# Get an array of hashes representing the result (column => value):
result.to_hash
# => [{"id" => 1, "title" => "title_1", "body" => "body_1"},
      {"id" => 2, "title" => "title_2", "body" => "body_2"},
      ...
     ]

result.to_hash.map(&:symbolize_keys)
# => [{:id => 1, :title => "title_1", :body => "body_1"},
      {:id => 2, :title => "title_2", :body => "body_2"},
      ...
     ]
```

[See the ActiveRecord::Result docs for more info](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Result.html).

Comment: Cannot be simpler and clearer than this. Thank you very much.

Comment: A note if your version of ActiveRecord is not recognising `to_hash` method: try `to_ary` instead. Strangely this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

**try this one :-**

```
data = Model_name.last

data.attributes
```