# How to convert activerecord results into an array of hashes including root

Tags: activerecord, hash

Let's say you want to

```
records = Model.all
records.to_a.map{|m| m.serializable_hash(:root => true)}
```

just like `to_json(:root => true)` does

```
[
  {
    "model": {
      "attribute_1": "value_1",
      "attribute_2": "value_2",
    }
  }
  ...
]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### as_json

```
records.as_json(:root => true)
```

### serializable_hash

```
records.to_a.map() {|x| 
  { x.class.model_name.element => x.serializable_hash() } 
}
```

This will not work with nested objects though