# How can I have ActiveRecord's pluck also return the column name for rendering in json?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
def jsontest
   @users = User.all.limit(10)
   render json: @users
end
```

yields

```
{
...

"id": 7,
"name": "Sage Smith",
"email": "example-6@railstutorial.org",
"created_at": "2013-10-17T02:29:15.638Z",
"updated_at": "2013-10-17T02:29:15.638Z",
"password_digest": "$2a$10$taHk3udtWN61Il5I18akj.E90AB1TmdL1BkQBKPk/4eZ7YyizGOli",
"remember_token": "118f807d0773873fb5e4cd3b5d98048aef4f6f59",
"admin": false

...
}
```

But I would like to omit certain certain fields from this API, so I use `pluck`

```
def jsontest
  @users = User.all.limit(10).pluck(:id, :name, :email, :created_at) ###
  render json: @users
end
```

but pluck returns an array of only values, when I would like to have each object's attributes accessible by hash key.

```
[
...

    7,
    "Sage Smith",
    "example-6@railstutorial.org",
    "2013-10-17T02:29:15.638Z"

...    

]
```

So how can I effectively pluck the values and their keys?

I realize I could sweep through @users and grab the keys before plucking and recreate the hash, but I'm expecting there to be some convenience method that does exactly what I want.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use `select` instead of `pluck`:

```
def jsontest
  @users = User.select('id, name, email, created_at').limit(10)
  render json: @users
end
```

Comment: Select has the performance penalty of instantiating an AR object per record, plus it's cumbersome if you're joining tables...

Comment: @bluehallu, on the other side, the other solutions to restore the keys after pluck also have performance penalties. I wonder which option is lighter: `select` or `pluck.map`. I would guess both have an equivalent impact. Hence, as being equals, `select` is cleaner.

Answer (score 53):

vee's answer is good, but I have one caveat. `select` instantiates a `User` for every row in the result, but `pluck` does not. That doesn't matter if you are only returning a few objects, but if you are returning large batches (50, 100, etc) you'll pay a significant performance penalty.

I ran into this problem, and I switched back to pluck:

```
#in user.rb
def self.pluck_to_hash(*keys)
  pluck(*keys).map{|pa| Hash[keys.zip(pa)]}
end

#in elsewhere.rb
User.limit(:10).pluck_to_hash(*%i[id name email created_at])
```

It's ugly, but it gets the hash you want, and fast.

**I've updated it to reflect Mike Campbell's comment on Oct 11.**

Comment: you can lose the splat and the flatten and make the hash instantiation easier and about 2x faster: `Hash[keys.zip(pa)]`

Comment: @MikeCampbell didn't really work for me — do you have the whole line?

Comment: @fatuhoku `pluck(*keys).map{|pa| Hash[keys.zip(pa)]}`

Comment: Using a splat for the arguments allows you to trop the `[]` around the params: `def self.pluck_to_hash(*keys)` allows `pluck_to_hash(:id, :name, :email, :created_at)`

Comment: Not work for me when trying to alias column name: `User.pluck_to_hash(['created_at AS time'])`

Comment: This needs to be added to active record. Anyone know how to do that?

Comment: @JaredMenard create  a pull request. http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/contributing_to_ruby_on_rails.html

Answer (score 14):

Created a simple `pluck_to_hash` gem to achieve this.
https://github.com/girishso/pluck_to_hash

Usage example..

```
Post.limit(2).pluck_to_hash([:id, :title])
#
# [{:id=>213, :title=>"foo"}, {:id=>214, :title=>"bar"}]
#

Post.limit(2).pluck_to_hash(:id)
#
# [{:id=>213}, {:id=>214}]
#

# Or use the shorter alias pluck_h

Post.limit(2).pluck_h(:id)
#
# [{:id=>213}, {:id=>214}]
#
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. See [How do I write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @lokson, this answer was originally a link. ByteHamster suggested including the actual code in case the link becomes invalid. This does happen sometimes and renders the answer worthless.

Comment: @Tass I saw own comment after some time and it's kinda rude, please accept my apologize.

Comment: No worries, @lokson. I didn't consider your response rude at all. I felt the need to explain why ByteHamster suggested added the code. It's certainly common enough to find an accepted answer for a question which is a "dead" link. Makes us all sad. Cheers!

Answer (score 6):

Fastest way to return hash of users with selected columns is use [`ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html#method-i-select_all) method.

```
sql = User.select('id, name, email, created_at').limit(10).to_sql
@users = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(sql)
render json: @users
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pull the data along with the column name as:

```
@users = User.all.limit(10)
                 .pluck(:id, :name, :email, :created_at)
                 .map {|id, name, email, created_at| { id: id, name: name, 
                                                       email: email, 
                                                       created_at: created_at } }
```

This will pull the data and map it according to how you want it. One advantage of using `pluck` over `select` is that you can use `joins` along with it.

Answer (score 0):

@andrewCone - It should be like this:

```
User.limit(:10).pluck_to_hash([:id, :name, :email, :created_at])
```

Answer (score 0):

@girishso's gem is great, but my project is in Rails 3. It doesn't work.

This [article](https://meltingice.dev/2013/06/11/pluck-multiple-columns-rails/) is helpful to me, or install [pluck_all](https://github.com/khiav223577/pluck_all) gem to achieve this.

Usage:

```
User.limit(10).pluck_all(:id, :name, :email, :created_at)
```

Comment: The article link is broken. Here's a link from Wayback Machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20180806182505/http://meltingice.net/2013/06/11/pluck-multiple-columns-rails/ (I could not edit the answer because 'Suggested edit queue is full' :-) )

Comment: Thanks. I just update the link :)