# Select always returns :id even if it is not included in the call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, select, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using `.select` to choose which field I want to return, I'm specifying all fields except `:id, :created_at and :updated_at`, anyways it still returns the `"id": null`.

I'm building an API with Ruby on Rails 5, as usual the fields :id, :created_at and :updated_at are created after running the migration, where `:id` is the primary key.

When I use `address.select(:name, :region, :province)`

I get:

```
[
{
    "id": null,
    "name": "Lorem Ipsum",
    "region": "some text",
    "province": "some more text"
},
{
    "id": null,
    "name": "Lorem Ipsum 1",
    "region": "some text 1",
    "province": "some more text 1"
}
]
```

But what I'm expecting is:

```
[
{
    "name": "Lorem Ipsum",
    "region": "some text",
    "province": "some more text"
},
{
    "name": "Lorem Ipsum 1",
    "region": "some text 1",
    "province": "some more text 1"
}
]
```

Hope my explanation was enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
render json: address.select(:name, :region, :province).to_json(except: :id)
```

Comment: Good idea @AbM. Much simpler than my answer :-)

Comment: Perfect! 
I did the following:

    module Response
      def json_response(object, status = :ok)
        render json: object, status: status, except: :id
      end
    end

And worked like a charm, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should use `pluck` instead of `select` if you don’t want to retrieve the id.

```
Address.pluck(:name, :region, :province)
```

That will return an array of values without the  id. I’m assuming you want the column names as well in which case you can add a method to the model:

```
def self.pluck_to_hash(keys)
  pluck(*keys).map{|pa| Hash[keys.zip(pa)]}
end

# use it with
Address.pluck_to_hash([:name, :region, :province])
```

`pluck_to_hash` method from https://stackoverflow.com/a/27995494/10987825