# How can I convert an array of ActiveRecord Relations into a hash that is keyed off of one of the parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, hash

I'm creating a raw SQL upsert and I have a fairly large array of ActiveRecord Relations that I need to convert to a hash. I need the hash to be keyed off of one of the parameters that I'm selecting so I can quickly get at the value.

[I found this response using as_json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15427936/how-to-convert-activerecord-results-into-a-array-of-hashes) and I can almost get what I need using that, but its not quite there.

```
profiles = Profile.all.select(:id, :foo)  #returns an array of ActiveRecord Relations
profiles = profiles.as_json
```

Yields

```
{:id => 123, :foo => "bar"}
{:id => 456, :foo => "baz"}
```

But what I'd like is

```
{123 => "bar", 456 => "baz"}
```

I realize that I could map the results of as_json to a new hash, but I have to run this fairly frequently on a few million records. This is also a small part of a larger rake task, and I'd like to keep looping over all of the records down to minimum.

My reason for doing this all manually instead of letting ActiveRecord handle it was that it was initially taking over 24 hours to run the task, and even using [activerecord-import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import) only sped it up to ~12 hours. [I chose to go with using raw sql based off the benchmarks made in this blogpost](https://www.coffeepowered.net/2009/01/23/mass-inserting-data-in-rails-without-killing-your-performance/)

Comment: What is your rails version?

Comment: I'm using Rails 4.2.4

Answer (score 5):

In Rails4, you can do

```
Profile.pluck(:id, :foo).to_h
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `select_all` method get an array of hash instead of ActiveRecord object, it is more faster and less memory consumption.

```
Profile.connection.select_all("select id, foo from profiles;")
=> [{"id" => xxx, "foo" => xxx}, {}, .....]
```

then convert the result to your desired format.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using this and it was much faster, so it wasn't a big performance hit to map that to the hash I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

On your `profile` model you can do this to get your desired result:

```
  def self.to_hash
    Hash[*all.map{|p| [p.id, p.foo]}.flatten]
  end
```

You can then call: `Profile.select(:id, :foo).to_hash`

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably bypass ActiveRecord and slurp the data straight out of the database into a Hash with something like this:

```
Profile.connection
       .execute('select id, foo from profiles')
       .each_with_object({}) { |row, h| h[row['id'].to_i] = row['foo'] }
```

Or better (IMO), bypass Rails and Ruby too and do everything you need to do inside the database with SQL, temp tables, etc. When you're working with large amounts of data, your best bet is usually to ignore your application completely and do everything inside the database; databases are great at working with large piles of data, that's what they do.