# How to merge two ActiveRecord queries into one hash and convert to JSON?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ajax, activerecord

I'm using AJAX to get some results, but the problem is I'm querying two separate models and I want to return both and their relationship to one another as one JSON object.

Here's an example of two models I'm trying to link together -

```
Car
  belongs_to :user

  :id
  :make
  :year
  :user_id

User
  has_many :cars

  :id
  :first_name
  :last_name
  :birthday
```

I'm trying to get it to look something like this -

```
{
  1: {
    id: 1,
    first_name: 'Joe'
    last_name: 'Smith'
    cars: {
      23: {
        id: 23,
        make: 'BMW',
        year: 2009,
        user_id: 1
      },
      24: {
        id: 24,
        make: 'Volvo',
        year: 2012,
        user_id: 1
      }
    }
  },
  2: {
    id: 2,
    first_name: 'Bob'
    last_name: 'Johnson'
    cars: {
      35: {
        id: 35,
        make: 'Ford',
        year: 2013,
        user_id: 2
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have associations between User and Car? What are they? Can you show that snippet of each model, please?

Comment: @jaydel alright I updated the question. Its just a standard belongs_to/has_many relationship.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new (private) method in your controller:

```
def format_json(users)
  result = {}
  users.each do |user|
    result[user.id] = user.formatted_data
  end
  return result
end
```

Change the action to return:

```
users = Users.includes(:cars).where("<your_where_clause>").limit(<n>)
render :json => { :result => format_json(users) }.to_json
```

## app/models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def formatted_data
    {
      :id         => self.id,
      :first_name => self.first_name,
      :last_name  => self.last_name,
      :cars       => self.get_car_info
    }
  end

  def get_car_info
    car_info = {}
    self.cars.each do |car|
      car_info[car.id] = car.info
    end
    return car_info
  end
end
```

## app/models/car.rb

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  def info
    {
      :id      => self.id,
      :make    => self.make,
      :year    => self.year,
      :user_id => self.user_id
    }
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This should work as well but I just thought my solution was more self-contained.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the `.as_json` I found detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15623280/772309) to convert ActiveRecord to a plain Ruby hash and passed that hash to the view.

```
user = User.find(params[:user_id].to_i)

@json = {}
@json[user.id] = user.as_json
@json[user.id]['cars'] = {}

user.cars.each do |car|
  @json[user.id]['cars'][car.id] = car.as_json
end

render json: { status: true, users: @json }
```